# Lucid Lynx login issue

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, gnome, metacity

Recently upgraded from Karmic to Lynx. Upgrade seemed to go well, no noticeable issues.

I logged in, and my window manager wasn't starting. An application would appear, but sans control buttons and border, so figured the windows manager needed to be given a swift kick. Opened a web browser and a quick google had me run "metacity --replace &" and everything popped up. I re-ran the Compiz configuration tool to enable my rotating desktop cube to the way I liked it, and had to reconfigure my desktop switcher to the right number of desktops (although the first time I ran it, it crashed on the panel and reloaded...odd, but once it relaunched it seemed fine.)

Today I installed updates, rebooted and logged in for the second time since my upgrade. Again, the window manager was dead, and my compiz settings were gone, and the workspaces were set back to four (and when I clicked on the preferences to change them, it crashed on the panel and reloaded again). Resetting everything made things look somewhat normal again.

I'm guessing it'll work until I reboot again. Googling around isn't turning up similar complaints about Lucid Lynx and the window manager. Before I go deleting preference files, anyone else know of this kind of issue and what could be done about it? Or should I start taking the stab in the dark approach of deleting preference files hoping one of them is corrupt or has something unsupported in it that's throwing LL for a loop?

Comment: i'd expect some things have changed in the preferences and that's where your trouble is coming from.  if you don't want to go digging through Gnome config files, just log out, login to a console terminal and move the Gnome-related dotfiles into some temp directory (~/tmp or so), then log back in and let Gnome give you default configs.  then you can retweak to taste, and your old configs are still around for reference or comparison.

Comment: That was my next plan of attack. I didn't know if maybe someone on the site had seen this behavior, but googling seemed to hint that this was an isolated incident so far... :-/